# bitnami postgres-ha helm standby pods keep restarting and recreating /bitnami/postgresql/data directory

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, high-availability

I've been trying to setup Bitnami Postgres-Ha cluster with 3 replicas, using 11.7.7 version of its helm [chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql-ha/11.7.7). Following are the steps I've done to stand it up, bring data and reinstall helm (to simulate k8 cluster restart of pod restart scenarios)

1. PVCs are created on top of NFS storage (with ownership - User=1001, Group=1001), after first helm install, the pods are running fine.
2. I created a database using schema from existing database, which is successfully replicated across standby pods.
   3)I subscribe primary pod to my existing database in order to bring existing data without downtime as per client requirements. Data is replicated successfully across all 3 pods (primary + 2 replicas), following which I remove subscription and change connection on application to ingest new data in this cluster.
3. it works fine for some time, new data is populated across the pods.
4. Simulation time: I stop application backend pod and uninstall/install postgres-ha cluster, at this stage cluster goes bonkers, standby pods never come back. as per kubectl logs from second replica pod, following is what I see

   ```
    postgresql-repmgr 04:55:58.80 INFO  ==> Cloning data from primary node...
        WARNING: following problems with command line parameters detected:
          -D/--pgdata will be ignored if a repmgr configuration file is provided
        NOTICE: destination directory "/bitnami/postgresql/data" provided
        INFO: connecting to source node
        DETAIL: connection string is: host=pg-cluster-postgresql-ha-postgresql-0.qa-pg-cluster-postgresql-ha-postgresql-headless.myns.svc.cluster.local port=5432 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr
        DETAIL: current installation size is 19 GB
        DEBUG: 3 node records returned by source node
        DEBUG: connecting to: "user=repmgr password=XXXXXX connect_timeout=5 dbname=repmgr host=qa-pg-cluster-postgresql-ha-postgresql-0.qa-pg-cluster-postgresql-ha-postgresql-headless.myns.svc.cluster.local port=5432 fallback_application_name=repmgr options=-csearch_path="
        DEBUG: upstream_node_id determined as 1000
        NOTICE: checking for available walsenders on the source node (2 required)
        NOTICE: checking replication connections can be made to the source server (2 required)
        WARNING: directory "/bitnami/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
        NOTICE: deleting existing directory "/bitnami/postgresql/data"
        DEBUG: replication slot "repmgr_slot_1002" exists but is inactive; reusing
        NOTICE: starting backup (using pg_basebackup)...
        INFO: executing:
          /opt/bitnami/postgresql/bin/pg_basebackup -l "repmgr base backup"  -D /bitnami/postgresql/data -h qa-pg-cluster-postgresql-ha-postgresql-0.dkp-qa-pg-cluster-postgresql-ha-postgresql-headless.myns.svc.cluster.local-p 5432 -U repmgr -c fast -X stream -S repmgr_slot_1002
   ```

And kubectl logs on first replica pod, logs are here.

```
 postgresql-repmgr 04:53:04.59 INFO  ==> Initializing Repmgr...
postgresql-repmgr 04:53:04.60 INFO  ==> Waiting for primary node...
postgresql-repmgr 04:53:04.61 DEBUG ==> Wait for schema repmgr.repmgr on 'qa-pg-cluster-postgresql-ha-postgresql-0.qa-pg-cluster-postgresql-ha-postgresql-headless.myns.svc.cluster.local:5432', will try 6 times with 10 delay seconds (TIMEOUT=60)
postgresql-repmgr 04:53:04.71 DEBUG ==> Schema repmgr.repmgr exists!
postgresql-repmgr 04:53:04.71 INFO  ==> Rejoining node...
postgresql-repmgr 04:53:04.73 INFO  ==> Cloning data from primary node...
WARNING: following problems with command line parameters detected:
  -D/--pgdata will be ignored if a repmgr configuration file is provided
NOTICE: destination directory "/bitnami/postgresql/data" provided
NOTICE: checking for available walsenders on the source node (2 required)
NOTICE: checking replication connections can be made to the source server (2 required)
WARNING: directory "/bitnami/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
NOTICE: deleting existing directory "/bitnami/postgresql/data"
NOTICE: starting backup (using pg_basebackup)...
```

The values that I've changed in values.yaml are here

```
#for postgresql:
 replicaCount: 3 
 syncReplication: true
#for repmgr:
repmgrUsername: repmgr
repmgrPassword: "myrepmgr_pass"
repmgrDatabase: repmgr
repmgrLogLevel: DEBUG
repmgrConnectTimeout: 5
repmgrReconnectAttempts: 2
repmgrReconnectInterval: 3
repmgrFenceOldPrimary: false
repmgrChildNodesCheckInterval: 5
repmgrChildNodesConnectedMinCount: 1
usePgRewind: false

#pgpool settings
maxConnections: "100"
postgresConnectionLimit: "10"
dbUserConnectionLimit: "100"
numInitChildren: "100"
reservedConnections: 0
maxPool: "100"
childMaxConnections: "100"
clientIdleLimit: "600"
connectionLifeTime: "600"
```

My PVCs are like following

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: data-pg-cluster-postgresql-ha-postgresql-0
  namespace: postgres-cluster
spec:
  storageClassName: default
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
```

I'm using postgres user just to access database. After reinstalling helm chart, my primary pod is running fine and still receiving new data but the standby pods keep crashing. Somehow replication process is deleting /bitnami/postgresql from standby pods upon reinstall. The data volume is around 20GB in primary which I believe is supposed to be synced to replicas but with these restarts, its going in infinite loop kind of situation. I'm stuck on this for few days, irony is that same helm chart is working fine in Azure. Can someone kindly advise what am I doing wrong here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using separate NFS PV manifests for each pod? If so how did you declare it?

Comment: I've once also spent a few days trying to make pgpool work - and found it unstable. Decided to ho with standard bitnamis chart `PostgreSQL` with one master <-> replication (hot standby). Working just fine

Comment: @wiktor Client has storage team which did the respective setup, essentially we have 3 separate mount points created on the NFS, which are then exposed through Kuberenetes PersistentVolumes.

Comment: please provide `yaml` code to show these PV/PVCs (as I see there are not declared in values used for helm)

Comment: I've updated it  with PVC  yaml. not sure who/why has clicked on "Close" for this question.

Comment: alright, and what about the PVs? also how are attaching these to pods if not with `values`?

Comment: actually, the issue is not with PV/PVC as such, since my /bitnami/postgresql directories are appearing in relevant volumes, with  correct user and group id  1001:1001